# Knowing the limit of $f'(x)$ find the limit of $f(x)$

Tags: limits, analysis, functions

We have that $f$ is differentiable on $(a, +\infty)$ with $a>0$.

I want to show that if $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=\ell}$, then there are the following cases:

- If $\ell>0$ then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty\ \text{ and } \ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\ell$$
- If $\ell<0$ then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=-\infty\ \text{ and } \ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\ell$$
- If $\ell=0$ then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=? \ \text{ and } \ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\ell$$

$$$$

Do we use the fact that $$f(x+1)-f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}f'(u)\,du$$ to find the limits of the function $f$ ?

Comment: Use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: You mean for the limits for $\frac{f(x)}{x}$, right? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: For that we have to calculate first the limit of $f(x)$ right? How can we do that knowing the limit of the  derivative? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: You don't need to worry about $f(x) $. L'Hospital's Rule works in two forms "$0/0$" and "$\text {anything} /\infty $". In the second case one doesn't bother about numerator and only ensures that denominator diverges to $\infty $ or $-\infty $. This fact about second case is not widely known.

Comment: Ahh I thought that we can use L'Hospital;s Rule when we have the case $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Does the case "anything$/\infty$" derive from one of the above two cases? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: No, it's the other way round. The case $\infty/\infty$ is part of $\text{anything}/\infty $ because "anything" includes $\infty$ also.

Comment: So doesn't a fraction have to be in the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ so that we are able to use L'Hospital's Rule? Can we use this also in the case $\text{anything}/\infty$ ? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Yes either the fraction should have both numerator and denominator tending to $0$ (first case) or just the denominator should tend to $\infty$ or $-\infty $ (second case) in order to apply L'Hospital's Rule. The second case is not well known (some teachers/instructors may also not be aware). So if you use this in exam write this explicitly about the second case.

Comment: How do we explain explicitly the second case? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: In your exam write like this : "contrary to the popular belief L'Hospital's Rule can be used in case when the denominator tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty $ without checking limit of numerator. Any proof of L'Hospital's Rule never uses any information about numerator when dealing with this case". Based on this the examiner can check proofs of L'Hospital's Rule  (if needed) and get convinced of your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \varepsilon>0 : $

Since $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f'\left(x\right)}=\ell $, there is some $ A_{1}\geq a $ such that $ \left(\forall x\geq A_{1}\right),\ \left|f'\left(x\right)-\ell\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \cdot $

Since $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{f\left(A\right)-A\ell}{x}}=0 $, there is some $ A_{2}\geq a $ such that $ \left(\forall x\geq A_{2}\right),\ \frac{\left|f\left(A\right)-A\ell\right|}{x}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $

For $ x\geq A=\max\left(A_{1},A_{2}\right) $, we have : \begin{aligned} \left|\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}-\ell\right|&=\frac{1}{x}\left|\int_{A}^{x}{\left(f'\left(t\right)-\ell\right)\mathrm{d}t}+f\left(A\right)-A\ell\right|\\ &\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_{A}^{x}{\left|f'\left(t\right)-\ell\right|\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\left|f\left(A\right)-A\ell\right|}{x}\\\left|\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}-\ell\right|&\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_{A}^{x}{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\,\mathrm{d}t}+ \frac{\varepsilon}{2}= \varepsilon-\frac{A\varepsilon}{2x}\leq \varepsilon\end{aligned}

Meaning, $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}=\ell \cdot $

Now since $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f\left(x\right)}=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{\underbrace{x}_{\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty}\underbrace{\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\right)}_{\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ell}} $, we should separate the cases to determine, according to the values of the constant $ \ell $, the value of $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f\left(x\right)} $ :

If $ \ell >0 $ the limit would be $ +\infty $, if $ \ell <0 $ the limit would be $ -\infty $, and when $ \ell =0 $ it gives an indeterminate form, so we can not conclude anything about its value.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks a lot!! :-) If we had that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=+\infty}$ then $\forall M>0 \ \exists A : \ \forall x>A : f'(x)>M$. 

We have that $$f(x)=\int_A^xf'(t)\, dt+f(A)>\int_A^xM\, dt+f(A)=M(x-A)+A$$ So we get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)>\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}(M(x-A)+A)=+\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}>\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{M(x-A)+A}{x}=M$$ Is this correct?

Comment: The first part that is proving that $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f\left(x\right)}=+\infty $ is correct. To prove that $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}=+\infty $, let's use the definition : For $ M>0 $ there is $ A_{1}>0 $ such that $ \left(\forall x>A_{1}\right),\ f'\left(x\right)>\frac{M}{2} $, and since $ \frac{A\left(M-2\right)}{2x}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $, there is $ A_{2}>0 $ such that $ \left(\forall x>A_{2}\right),\ \frac{A\left(M-2\right)}{2x}<\frac{M}{2} \cdot $

Comment: As you said, for $ x>A=\max\left(A_{1},A_{2}\right) $ we have $ f\left(x\right)>\frac{M}{2}\left(x-A\right)+A $, thus $ \frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}>\frac{M}{2}-\frac{A\left(M-2\right)}{2x}>M $, hence $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}}=+\infty \cdot $

Comment: Ahh I see!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: I have a question... We don't know that the integral exists, do we? So we cannot use integrals here, can we?

Comment: @MaryStar: the integral may not exist as $f'$ may not be integrable. A proof can be given using mean value theorem directly (this is also the way L'Hospital's Rule is proved via Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem).

Comment: So should we use here Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem or the simple Mean Value Theorem? If we use the simple version do we do the following? Let $c\in (a,x)$ the from MVT we have $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Then we take the limit $c\rightarrow \infty$ then it must be $x\rightarrow \infty$, or not? So we get $$\lim_{c\rightarrow \infty}f'(c)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$ Is the last step correct? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Or is the last step wrong since we don't know the value of $f(a)$ ? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @MaryStar: wait I will provide an answer based on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and we assume that $f'(x) \to l$ as $x\to\infty $. Here $l$ is a real number. The proof below works with minor modifications when $l=\pm\infty $.

By definition of limit there is a positive number $a$ such that $$|f'(x) - l|<\frac {\epsilon} {3}\tag{1}$$ whenever $x>a$. Next consider the algebraic identity $$\frac{f(x)} {x}-l =\left\{\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a}-l\right\} +\frac{f(a)} {x} \tag{2}$$ (the above is just plain algebra with no magic involved). And then our strategy is to ensure that both terms in $(2)$ are small. Clearly the second term is less than $\epsilon /3$ in absolute value if $x>\dfrac{3(|f(a)|+1)}{\epsilon}=b$. Using mean value theorem the first term in $(2)$ can be written as $$\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)f'(\xi)-l=f'(\xi) - l-\frac{af'(\xi)} {x} \tag{3}$$ for some $\xi\in(a, x) $. The absolute value of last term in above equation does not exceed $a(|l|+(\epsilon/3))/x$ and hence does not exceed $\epsilon /3$ if $$x>\frac{3a(|l|+(\epsilon/3))}{\epsilon}=c$$ Let $x>N=\max(a, b, c) $ and then we have via triangle inequality applied on $(2)$ and $(3)$ $$\left|\frac{f(x)} {x} - l\right|\leq |f'(\xi) - l|+a\cdot\frac{|f'(\xi) |} {x}+\frac{|f(a) |} {x} \tag{4}$$ where $\xi$ is some number between $a$ and $x$. The way $a,b,c, N$ are defined each term in right side of $(4)$ is less than $\epsilon /3$ when $x>N$ and therefore the left hand side of $(4)$ is less than $\epsilon$ whenever $x>N$. By definition of limit we have $$\lim\limits _{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x)} {x} =l$$ as desired.

Note that given $l$ and $\epsilon$ we first determine $a$. Then using $a$ and $\epsilon$ we determine $b$. And $c$ is based on $a,l, \epsilon $. Since $l$ is fixed as a part of question, the numbers $a, b, c, N$ depend only on $\epsilon $.

Comment: For $b$ why do we take $\dfrac{3(|f(a)|+1)}{\epsilon}$ and not $\dfrac{3|f(a)|}{\epsilon}$ ? Why do we need the term $+1$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: $|f(a) |$ may be $0$. And we want $a, b, c$ stuff to be positive. Anyway this trick is not needed here as $f(a) =0$ will make that term vanish and therefore automatically less than $\epsilon /3$.

Comment: Ahh ok! Thanks for the clarification! All the rest is very clear to me! Thanks a lot!! Now I am looking at the case where $l$ is infinity.

Comment: We suppose that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=+\infty$. Then for each $M>0$ there is a positive number $a$ s.t. $\forall x>a$: $f'(x)>M$.
We consider $$\frac{f(x)} {x} =\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)\cdot\frac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a} +\frac{f(a)} {x}$$  Using mean value theorem the first part of the avove equation can be written as $$\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)f'(\xi)=f'(\xi) -\frac{af'(\xi)} {x},\ \xi\in(a, x)$$ We have that $$\frac{f(x)} {x}= f'(\xi) -a\cdot\frac{f'(\xi) } {x}+\frac{f(a) } {x}$$ We want that it is greater than a positive number, right? But how? Or is something wrong so far?

Comment: @MaryStar: the first term is greater than $M$ and other terms tend to $0$.

Comment: @MaryStar: Given $M>0$ find $a$ such that $f'(x) >2(M+1)$ if $x>a$. And choose $b>0$ such that $a/x<1/2$ if $x>b$ (we can take $b=2a$). This makes $(1-a/x)((f(x)-f(a))/(x-a))>M+1$.

Comment: @MaryStar: and last term can be mad less than $1$ in absolute value if $x>|f(a)|$.

Comment: This is an other way than what I did, it is not the same one, right?